# Cast IPoint variable to IGeometry

Tags: c#, arcmap, arcobjects

I am working in ArcMap. I have a feature class layer (polyline) that has points in it. For each point, I want to cast/convert it to a geometry and place it in a separate layers attribute table; under the shape field column.

I also try and do other calculations on Shape field column in the table (such as a distance between points) and I get an error saying "The operation was attempted on an empty geometry.". This leads me to believe that I am not inserting the value into the table correctly. Furthermore, it leads me to believe I am not casting correctly or creating the IGeometry variable correctly either.

Also, when I try and look at the attribute table, it shows PointZM in the 'Shape' field column, however, when looking at the map, I cant see any points in Arcmap. My code is below.

```
IFeatureLayer _SelectedLayer = MultiItemList._CapturedFeatureLayer;
IFeatureClass _SelectedFeatClass = _SelectedLayer.FeatureClass;

IDataset _SelectedFeatureDataset = (IDataset)_SelectedFeatClass;
IWorkspace _SelectedWorkspace = (IWorkspace)_SelectedFeatureDataset.Workspace;
string _SelectedPath = _SelectedWorkspace.PathName;

IFeature _mySelectedFeature = _SelectedFeatClass.GetFeature(0);
IGeometry _theGeometry = _mySelectedFeature.Shape as IGeometry;      

IPolyline _PolyLine = (IPolyline)_theGeometry;                
IPointCollection _pointsCollection = (IPointCollection)_PolyLine;

if (_pointsCollection.PointCount>=2)            
{
   IEnumVertex2 _enumVertex = _pointsCollection.EnumVertices as IEnumVertex2;
   IPoint _queryVertex = new PointClass();  
   _enumVertex.Reset();                                                         
   IPoint _outVertex;                                                    
   int partIndex;
   int vertexIndex;
   _enumVertex.Next(out _outVertex, out partIndex, out vertexIndex);

   while (_outVertex != null)
   {
     ITable LeveePointsTable = (ITable)LeveePoints_featureClass;
     int ShapeIndex = LeveePointsTasble.FindField("Shape");
     IRow LeveePointsRow = LeveePointsTable.CreateRow();

     // trying to cast IPoint to IGeometry
     IGeomerty _myPoints = (Igeometry)_outVertex

     LeveePointsRow.set_Value(ShapeIndex, _MyPoints);
   }
}
```

Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm going to assume you set a breakpoint after this line (it won't compile for at least three distinct reasons, but maybe you retyped it): `IGeomerty _myPoints = (Igeometry)_outVertex`. When you did that, was `_myPoints` null? Another point to ponder is whether or not the actual runtime type of _outVertex implements `IGeometry`. You checked that, right?

Comment: Yes, _outVertex (IPoint) does implement IGeometry. With the line: ' IGeomerty _myPoints = (Igeometry)_outVertex ' I can use a MessageBox to ouput the X and Y coordinate of the variable _outVertex and it will display them. Plus I don't get a casting error on this line. I did not initialize the variable '_myPoints' to anything though. Perhaps I should initialize it to null first.

Comment: No, don't initialize `_myPoints` to null; you're already initializing it to `(IGeometry)_outVertex` and that's all you need.

Comment: Apologies as well, but this probably won't compile because I left out a part at the top. [MulitItemList] is a separate class. The class (or really container) is a container (or list) for feature class layers. Also, the above function is under the OnClick() method. My hunch was that I wasn't fully creating the IGeometry variable (if that makes sense). I'm thinking I should be incorporating a spatial reference with this IGeometry variable...perhaps the reason why when I try to insert it into the table, its inserted as an empty geometry. Its a possibility. Again, sorry for the omitted code.

Answer (score 0):

I would do the following:

1. Try to get the geometry directly from the IPointCollection object, something like this:

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < pointCollection.PointCount; i++)
   {
       var p = pointCollection.get_Point(i);
   }
   ```
2. Apply the geometry to the shape property using the `IFeature` interface:

   ```
   ((IFeature)row).Shape = p;
   ```

BTW: If you are creating a feature inside a feature class, why not use the `IFeature` and `IFeatureClass` interfaces, instead of `ITable` and `IRow`? There are a lot of problems using the "Shape" string directly to get the shape field, due to the name depends on the database type.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things in your code that I won´t mention in the comments to make it easier to read them.

First off you should definitly cash the results of searching for a field. Doing this within a loop is not recommended.

However - and this is the second point - you won´t need to search for the shape-field, you can simply take the geometriy-field from the featureclass - no need to cast to `ITable`.

Third your loop never terminates as your reference to `_outVertex` is allways the same. I assume you want to get the next vertex within your collection using `_enumVertex.Next(out _outVertex, out partIndex, out vertexIndex)`.

Fourth you don´t need to cast to `IGeometry` as `IPoint` should already *inherit* that interface. Thus everything implementing  the latter should also *implicitely* implement the former interface.

Fifth and last you can directly access and iterate the `IPointCollection` without casting to `IEnumVertex`.

So after having said this your code could be simplified to this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < _pointsCollection.PointCount && _pointsCollection.PointCount >= 2; i++)
{
    IFeature newFeature = LeveePoints_featureClass.CreateFeature();
    // further attributes on the feature

    newFeature.Shape = _pointsCollection.get_Point(i);
}
```

Anyway I doubt all this will actually *solve* your issue as updates are not automatically mirrored in the view - in your case ArcMap - because they are internally cached to avoid massivly redrawing the whole screen after every update. To draw those updates from the cash you can use `IActiveView.PartialRefresh`.